# Scipy binom pmf for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

I have 3 dataframes, `df1` is 18x19, `df2` is 18x1 and `df3` is 18x19. I want a new dataframe which gives `df4=scipy.stats.binom.pmf(df1,df2,df3)` and I am not able to run it for dataframes. So for example

```
df4[0,0] = scipy.stats.binom.pmf(df1[0,0],df2[0,0],df3[0,0])
```

or

```
df4[2,3] = scipy.stats.binom.pmf(df1[2,3],df2[2,0],df3[2,3])
```

and so on.

I have tried using `map` function but it is not working in this case. I can use loops but that wouldn’t be an efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
# create the dataset
row = 18
col = 19
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,20,size=(row,1)))
df1 = pd.DataFrame({c: [np.random.randint(0, df2.loc[r,0]) for r in range(row)] for c in range(col)})
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,1, size = (row,col)))

# implementation 
#  can use 
# row, col = df1.shape

df4 = pd.DataFrame({c: [
                    stats.binom.pmf(df1.loc[r,c],df2.loc[r,0],df3.loc[r,c]
                ) for r in range(row)
                ] for c in range(col)})
```